# How to set custom background color of UITableViewCell even there's no data inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to accomplish something like this :

[image: Table view cell]

see there's only one data but, background color continue until end.

I understand I can do inside tableview delegate of `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. but then it doesn't go to empty cell, hence my empty cell always be white.

Comment: Add a UIlabel that fit to the Cell . and add background color for it ..

Comment: If cell is not prepared then how could u set background color to cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following code to display cell alternative color even if cell is not initialized.I have done this work on scrollViewDidScroll as showing below:--

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tblView.frame];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    UIView *cellView;

    int y=0;
    int i=0;

    for (UIView *view in tblView.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"_UITableViewSeparatorView"]) {

            cellView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 44)];

            if (i%2==0) {
                cellView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            }else{
                cellView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
            }

            [view addSubview:cellView];
            i++;
        }
    }

    tblView.backgroundView=view;
}
```

And got the correct result on scrolling table view. But the problem is it works when user scrolls the tableView atleast once a time.
If you will get success to fire event on tableView completes its reloading.Then it will be fine.

Here is output I got on scrolling tableView.

[image]

I also write this method to call didScrollMethod manually but doesn't seems to work perfectly.

```
[tblView.delegate scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)tblView.superclass];
```

But calling method like code below absolutely works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    tblView=[[MyFirstView alloc] init];
    tblView.delegate=self;
    [tblView setFrame:self.view.frame];

    [self.view addSubview:tblView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [tblView.delegate scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)tblView.superclass];
}
```

Means after loading tableView in viewDidLoad call didScroll in viewDidAppear works fine.

Insert below code if fluctuates first row while scrolling.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Hercules, you're bringing too much complexity in the code. check my answer here.

Comment: there's a bug though, whenever I scroll down, my first row label always disappear. did you encounter this?

Comment: I checked there is one solution for this. pass nil UIView as headerView.

Comment: Wow, nice!. I also added `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` to 0.1f, to avoid header that I don't want. so it really did the trick, I guess, the scroll messed-up the first row, which in this trick the empty header 0.1f of height.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `backgroundColor` to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell`.

Sample as below:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"]autorelease];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

To have alternate colors in your cells of tableView, you can do the following;

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"]autorelease];

    }

    if(indexPath.row % 2)
    {
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else
    {
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I want different color background, not one color for all rows. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If number of rows is 0 then what will you do @CodenameLambda1 read question carefully then answer it.He is asking for the condition when cell is not there in the tableView means numberOfRowInSection is 0.CellForRow will never executes in that condition

Comment: I can understand but don't worry you won't get a "divide zero" error. 

0 % 2 = 0

Check it..

Comment: When numberOfRowsInSection is 0 then tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method is never called by tableView. Further, a tableView with zero rows is not useful to anyone.

Comment: he want to show blank table with no data in it along with alternative color.Otherwise many answers are available on stack.Don't u think so why he need to ask this question if answer is already available on the net.

Comment: Oh I see, the asker means "no cell" when he says "empty cell". Well your answer is proper in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A table with plain style doesn't show rows below the last row so there is no way to produce the desired effect using table view cells. About your only option would be to create a view with the alternating pattern and make the view the table view's footer view.

This view would need to deal with being updated as the number of actual rows in the table changes to/from odd and even. And you need to make it tall enough so if the user scrolls the table up a bunch, the footer still reaches the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup some placeholder cells in addition to your cell with 'Monthly meeting', something like:

1. return amount of rows as 1 + (rows to fill screen) in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`
2. In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - check for index path of the cell, if its row = 0, then this is your action cell, otherwise, update cells background, do the same in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. Make sure to remove selectionStyle for your placeholder cells.

Or, you can use 2 cells - first one - again, your 'Monthly meeting' cell, and second one - a cell with height enough to cover screen from first cell to the bottom with image of striped cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do. Just have as many items in your data source array as you want to see rows, and have all but the first one be empty strings. In willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: apply a background color to all the odd numbered cells.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@"Monthly Meeting",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@""];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:232/255.0 green:238/255.0 blue:222/255.0 alpha:1];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set backgroundColor to the contentView of a UITableViewCell with the help of simple mathematics, Example:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

if (cell==nil)
 {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"]autorelease];
    if (i%2==0) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
    }else{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't help my case. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only running for available rows. as for empty row/cell will not run this method.